# How to make Nhibernate not to persist the changes in object to the database

Tags: nhibernate

There is a collection of data in the database on which a integration test is run. For preventing NHibernate persisting objects modification in the database an EventListener that inherits from **DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener** was implemented.

Then there is a method:

```
public override void OnSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent @event)
{
  @event.Session.CancelQuery();
  Trace.TraceWarning("NhibernateSaveUpdateCanceler: Persistence will be ignored.");
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work as expected. So intended behavior is to catch the moment when changes are written in the database and cancel it somehow though leaving objects as there are so modification on them can be validated.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Cannot do this because there are multiple transaction in the tested method so there is contradiction in requirements by persisting changes so that there are available for all transaction from one side and that changes are not persistent in the database from the other.

Comment: The intend is to make integration tests which will allow checking the objects for modification but whose changes won't be reflected in the database, thus allowing multiple test runs on same set of data.

Comment: ... but how would you run tests with multiple transactions? You mentioned it in a comment on the answer of Fran. This can't work. And more important: within the same transaction, NH needs to flush changes to make subsequent queries work. If you suppress flushing, you'll break it.

Comment: Stefan you are right. If transient objects is used in another transaction a database query returns old data so the changes are lost. I ended up canceling changes introduced by test in TearDown method.

Comment: I'm running test on a sqlite in-memory database. It is very fast. I create a brand new database for every single test. You only need to keep a single connection open during the test to keep the db alive. And only create the session factory once, because this is slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

re-write your integration test with an Integration test fixture base.  in the base class create:
 a fixture setup that initializes nhibernate and creates a session factory
 a fixture teardown that closes the session factory
 a test setup that creates a session and transaction
 a test teardown that rolls back the transaction and closes the session.

like this

```
[TestFixture]
public abstract class TestFixtureBase
{
    protected ISessionFactory SessionFactory { get; private set; }
    protected ISession Session { get; private set; }
    protected ITransaction Tx { get; private set; }

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public virtual void SetUp()
    {
        var nh = new NHInit();

        nh.Initialize();

        SessionFactory = nh.SessionFactory;
    }

    [TestFixtureTearDown]
    public virtual void TearDown()
    {
        SessionFactory.Close();
    }


    [SetUp]
    public void Test_Set_Up()
    {
        Session = SessionFactory.OpenSession();
        Tx = Session.BeginTransaction();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void Test_tear_down()
    {
        Tx.Rollback();
        Tx.Dispose();
        Session.Close();
    }
}
```

then write your test.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do this because there are multiple transaction inside tested code. Though it is a good idea when testing smaller chunks of functionality.

Answer (score 2):

The SaveOrUpdate event listener is called when `session.Save` or `session.Update` is called. When changes are flushed, the FlushEntity event is called for each entity. Implement `IFlushEntityEventListener`.